# Can we display a new view page by calling the controller using ajax in mvc 4 razor

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to display a new page (new url) to be displayed while clicking on a button from index page.
I tried it by using the following code:

```
 $('#message_submit').on('click', function () {

            var l = window.location;
            var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host;

            var datavalue = window.globalVar;
            var value = ($("input[name=Options]:checked").val());
            if (value == 1) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    url: base_url + '/ProductSpecific/Index',
                    data: { option: datavalue },

                //    success: function (data) {
                //        alert("success");
                //    },

                //    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //        alert("something went wrong");
                //}

                });
            }
        });
```

I need to display the index page of ProductSpecific controller.
But it is redirecting to the same page from where I clicked the submit button.Can I prevent this?Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `e.preventDefault()`. Like this:

```
$('#message_submit').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // More code here
});
```

So it will prevent the form to submit.

Comment: e.preventDefault() prevents the default submit action ,but I need to submit to /ProductSpecific/Index and display the view of index.But now it displays the same page from I clicked the submit button.I need to prevent automatic return from  /ProductSpecific/Index.Any other solution rather than ajax?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can submit the form to /productspecific/index with ajax. In the server side return the view's html and display it using java script (or replace the current html with the new)